# RMM Save to Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email, reply-mail-management

Can we set up a script in RMM to save email responses into a data extension? My original idea was to set up an inbox parse content and then ship it to an SFTP, but, that is less than ideal if there is an out-of-the-box solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. You would need to create an RMM Triggered Send. To do this, create an email, which will either be sent as an auto-reply or forwarded to an email. For this scenario, let's assume you are forwarding the email reply (as per the default RMM behavior).

Your email would contain something like this:

```ampscript
%%[
InsertDE('RMM Reply DE',
'JobId', _RMM_JobID,
'ListId', _RMM_ListID,
'BatchId', _RMM_BatchID,
'SubscriberKey', _RMM_RecipientSubscriberKey,
'EmailAddress', _RMM_RecipientEmailAddress,
'ReplyMessage', _replycontent
)
]%%
%%_RMM_ReplyBodyHTML%%
```

This assumes that you have a DE named 'RMM Reply DE'. I would not use any primary keys in this DE (to accommodate for the scenario where a Subscriber replies multiple times). The DE has the field names JobId, ListId etc (refer to arguments in the `InsertDE()` function above). Set the 'ReplyMessage' field as unlimited (by removing the length value), as the `_replycontent` personalization string is an abstract of the first 10,000 characters from the body of the email reply, in plain text format.

You can then create a Triggered Send Definition for the email and choose it as a 'Forward using triggered send' option in the Sender Profile.

When the Subscriber replies to an email, their reply will be stored in the DE and their formatted reply (along with the original message) will be forwarded to the email address that you defined in the Sender Profile.

For more information, refer to [this video I created on RMM Triggered Sends](https://mc.chat/reply-mail-management-rmm-triggered-sends-in-salesforce-marketing-cloud/).