# Retrieve subscribers who hit reply to an email

Tags: marketing-cloud, reply-mail-management

We want to update a DE when a subscriber replies to a particular email.

I followed this article and added the suggested code snippet to my email.
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000392599&type=1

I created a DE called 'replies'

I sent a test email using journey builder and replied to that email.

I see a row created in the 'replies' DE but no data. (image below)

[image]

Is this the right solution for my use case.

Comment: Does the DE actually show that it now has 1 record? Do you have RMM already configured in your account?

Comment: Yes it is showing 1 record but no data. I am using a custom sender profile and I have replies going to a specific mailbox from there. I have **Forward using triggered send ** and **Reply using triggered send** ticked in this custom sender profile.

Comment: @catchingup you would need to check the RMM (Reply Mail Management) in your MC first like Zuzanna mentioned above, if it hasn't been configured yet it will show exactly the issue you are facing. That was what I experienced before

Comment: I will test the RMM configuration and revert. thank you.

Comment: Resolved. 1. I had to create a triggered response email which contained the code snippet. 2. I then chose this email within the Sender profile as an **Forward using triggered send** and **Reply using triggered send** 3. This article helped. <https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/337372/rmm-save-to-data-extension>