# append parameters from DE into triggered response email

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I refer to my previous query which was resolved and works as intended.
[Retrieve subscribers who hit reply to an email](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/399966/retrieve-subscribers-who-hit-reply-to-an-email)

We now want to pass a parameter from the sendDE into the triggered response email and have it update the 'Replies' DE. Is this possible?

Below is me setting the parameter in the email that is being sent from the DE.

```
Set @appnum = [ApplicationNumber]
```

Below is my code in the triggered response email. This email fires when a customer hits reply to the above email.

```
%%[
Set @subscriberID = _RMM_SubscriberID
Set @email = _RMM_RecipientEmailAddress
Set @reply = _replycontent
Set @jobid = _RMM_JobID
Set @batchid = _RMM_BatchID

Set @appnum = RequestParameter ('appnum')

UpsertDE("Replies",1,"SubscriberID",@subscriberID,"Email",@email,"reply",@reply,"JobID",@jobid,"BatchID",@batchid,"ApplicationNumber",@appnum)
]%%

The output i am getting is that the RequestParameter field is not passing. Everything else does.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to do a lookup to the sendDE.
I do not know what fields are present in the sendDE so I am making an assumption it would have to be something like this:

```
set @appnun = Lookup("sendDE","ApplicationNumber","Email", @email)
```

Of course you can use something else than email or a combination of fields to find the correct record in the sendDE.

Doc: https://ampscript.guide/lookup/

Comment: A great suggestion. I now have this working. Thank you.